# Discrete math and recursion problem.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

I was recently reading up examples on recursion and how it relates to induction and there's this question I am not sure about.

Q: 
Let $$b_1=3$$
$$b_n=n(n+2)$$

From that question I wanted to do the n+1th step as well for the recursion process and i got this:

$$b_{n+1} = b_n+3$$

however, that is wrong and apparently it is missing a $+2n$ in it:

$$b_{n+1}=b_n+2n+3$$

Can someone please explain how the book got $2n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$b_n=n(n+2)$$
$$b_{n+1}=(n+1)(n+3)=n(n+3)+1(n+3)=n(n+2)+n+n+3=b_n+2n+3$$

Answer (score 2):

$b_{n+1}=(n+1)(n+3)=n^2+4n+3=n(n+2)+2n+3=b_n+2n+3$

Comment: Ohhh okay, thank you both for answering and i totally forgot that you can break 4n into 2n + 2n to get b_n, for some reason it just did'nt occur to me when I was expanding it.